# How do I change the theme of a learnr tutorial?

Tags: r, shiny, learnr

I am trying to change the theme of the learnr tutorial document from the default "rstudio" to something else. I've looked at the [cran documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/learnr/learnr.pdf) and it seems to imply that I can use any of the following visual themes ("rstudio", default", "cerulean", "journal", "flatly", "readable", "spacelab", "united", "cosmo", "lumen", "paper", "sandstone", "simplex", or "yeti"). This is what my YAML looks like

```
---
title: "The Negative Binomial Distribution"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---
```

To clarify, I want to change the entire outputted document (background color, font, ect.) not just one particular aspect of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly your question is, but if you want to apply one of the themes you simply add it like in the example below:

```
---
title: "The Negative Binomial Distribution"
output: 
   learnr::tutorial:
       theme: "united" 
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---
```

Comment: Thank you!! I took a looong summer break from any kind of coding and couldn't remember how to change the theme!

Comment: You can define the learnr tutorial document variables mentioned on this document https://pkgs.rstudio.com/learnr/reference/tutorial.html